# django is not able to read csv files for plotting highchart in javascript and html template

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts, django-templates

Using js and html (highchart),graph gets plotted on local server without django but inside django it is not able to plot it correctly.

Comment: We will need to see some code if you want help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i havent added the csv file folder to STATIC_DIRS. Also, while accessing any external file we need to add static befiore it like 
{% static "data.csv" %}
after that,it starts working